# How to find out type args of a superclass?

Tags: scala, reflection

I have

```
trait Foo[T]
class Bar extends Foo[String]
```

If I do `typeOf[Foo[String]].typeArgs`, I get `String` back.

But `typeOf[Bar].baseClasses.flatMap(_.typeArgs)` is empty.

Is it impossible to find the actual complete super-type and a given type?
(If it helps, I am actually writing a macro, so all the compile-time info should still be there ... though I don't think it actually matters, because I am only looking at types here, not actual objects) ...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but types are never applied for you OOTB. You have to take type parameters and arguments, create a map/2 lists with argument symbol and counterpart parameter type and then use `substituteTypes` or similar shenanigans. E.g. for subtypes it looks like this (I expect supertype to be similar):

- Scala 2

  ```
  // A is a c.WeakTypeTag[A]
  // subtype is a Symbol of A's subtype
  val sEta = subtype.toType.etaExpand
  sEta.finalResultType.substituteTypes(
    sEta.baseType(A.tpe.typeSymbol).typeArgs.map(_.typeSymbol),
    A.tpe.typeArgs
  )
  ```
- Scala 3

  ```
  // A is a scala.quoted.Type[A]
  // subtype is a Symbol of A's subtype
  subtype.primaryConstructor.paramSymss match {
    // subtype takes type parameters
    case typeParamSymbols :: _ if typeParamSymbols.exists(_.isType) =>
      // we have to figure how subtypes type params map to parent type params
      val appliedTypeByParam: Map[String, TypeRepr] =
        subtype.typeRef
         .baseType(TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol)
         .typeArgs
         .map(_.typeSymbol.name)
         .zip(TypeRepr.of[A].typeArgs)
         .toMap
      val typeParamReprs: List[TypeRepr] = typeParamSymbols.map(_.name).map(appliedTypeByParam)
      subtype.typeRef.appliedTo(typeParamReprs)
    // subtype is monomorphic
    case _ =>
      subtype.typeRef
  ```

Of course, in cases like GADT, you'd better write a set of tests to make sure you haven't missed anything, because with the reflection (even compile time) a lot of things you take for granted is gone.

Comment: Ok, after "massaging" it a little to fix incorrect refs etc, I think I have gotten it to [work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/spzoLli8SpaB47nSSBe1rQ) ... looks like `etaExpand` and `baseType`  is what I was missing ... it seems to do the trick. Damnit, I have no idea why it needs to be so damn complicated ... this thing is really poorly designed :(

Comment: In S2 it wasn't, that's the point of S3's macros rewrite. A PhD student created an experimental feature which kinda exposed the raw AST but also not really, to try out if LISP-like macros can be a thing (S2 macros). And then another guy showed that you can implement generic programming on top of it (Shapeless), and suddenly 90% of projects started relying on an alpha feature. And then no improvement was possible without making many people angry (breaking change). Scala 3 gradually adds utilities but the team is very cautious to avoid letting whole community rely on some alpha feature again.

Comment: Which is why Scala 2 macros are a magnificent source of pitfalls, although with richer API, and Scala 3 has much better API - for things it has API, because for some it doesn't. If you will work with S2 macros further, you'll discover that: incremental compilation can make macro forget that some sealed trait has subtypes; be oblivious how to communicate if Java class has a constructor; create an invalid tree, which you can fix by `c.typecheck(c.untypecheck)` (printing seemingly the same tree as before, but now it compiles), etc. If someone defends S2 macros they didn't work with them enough.

Comment: Just to be clear: for the first attempt published to get feedback, Scala 2 macros were already amazing and showed a lot of insight. It's the absurdly fast adaptation that made it impossible to improve upon the design without causing uproar.

Comment: Well, I haven't done much with scala3 yet, but looking at your snippets, it appears, that this particular use case is actually significantly _worse_ in scala3 than it was in scala2  (like many others I have encountered before – outside of macros – which is one of the big reasons, I still don't have very much experience with it)

Comment: It is worse because authors wait before putting things on prod to until they make sure they make sense and are consistent. Try to implement e.g. support for Java Enums (on Scala 3 supporting Scala 3 enums automatically covered Java enums, on Scala 2 I had to implement type refinement based on parsing lambda tree) or using any type with HKT (Scala 2 has no way of summoning type constructor - you have to summon WeakTypeTag with types correctly applied, turn it to c.Type and then extract .typeConstructor - and you can easily apply types to it in such a buggy way that the code will not compile).